# Getting whole page as response in jQuery aJax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've tried to echo String as error messages, but still I get distorted whole page as response in Jquery Ajax, though on correct input I get redirected to the right page.

**php**

```
if($_GET['action']=="login"){
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username']);
    $password = md5($salt.mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password']));
    try{
        validateLoginInputs();
         loginUser($username, $password);
          echo "1";
    } catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();     //I think something is wrong with this line
    }
}
```

**function - loginUser**

```
    function loginUser($username,$password){
global $link;
    $query =  "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password' LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query); 
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    if(!$row){
        throw new Exception("Username or Password didn't match");
        }   
}
```

**jQuery**

```
 else if ($("#loginorsignup").val()==="1") {
  $.ajax({
   url: "action.php?action=login",
   type: "POST",
   data: "username="+$("#username").val()+"&password="+$("#password").val(),
   success: function(response){
     if(response!=1){
      console.log(response);    // getting html of index.php When username or password is incorrect
      $("#userWarnings").html(response).show();  
    }else if(response==1){
      console.log(response);
      window.location.assign("home.php");
    }
       }
     });
}
```

**Container for displaying Error**

```
 <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert" id="userWarnings">
         </div>
```

Comment: Could change `echo "1";` to `exit(1)`. I personally would send JSON back, along with the correct content type headers.  Eg. `{success: false, message: 'some error message'}`

Comment: That&#39;s a nice idea, It didn&#39;t came across my mind as I was following a video tutorial, will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest change this function

```
function loginUser($username,$password){
    global $link;
    $query =  "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query); 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if($row){
       $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
       $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now if this function return true then user exists . Then

```
if($_GET['action']=="login"){
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username']);
    $password = md5($salt.mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password']));
    try{
        validateLoginInputs();
        echo loginUser($username, $password) ? '1' : 'Username or Password didn\'t match';

    } catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

You dont have to make any changes in your Frontend (JQuery) code.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I am trying to do this with exception handling, you're recommending to take away that part ?

Comment: yes because throwing exception is always pain in code, you have to handle all exception cases in your frontend code . Instead you directly echo it since it is simple check you're doing in frontend `response==1` .

Comment: Okay, but I mentioned above that I tried to echo string as error message, still i am getting page as response when username doesn't exist. What might be causing that?

Comment: check now i have made changes inside the function `loginUser` . Hope this solves your problem now.

Comment: didn't work! I guess at this point, i'd be better off righting it over again and debugging every step.